How to add VPCE endpoint Id for the Private REST API deployed using ZAPPA
Following the documentation from the Zappa Serverless: https://github.com/zappa/Zappa
I have hosted a REST API in AWS API gateway which is configured as PRIVATE endpoint. I have added the relevant resource policy as well. But i see that the VPCE ID is not added in the api settings which is required for the PRIVATE endpoints to work and i could not find any property where i can define this.
Do you know how to add this or what is the property called in zappa_settings.json. My zappa settings for private endpoint looks like below:
{
    "common": {
        "app_function": "app.app",
        "aws_region": "eu-central-1",
        "profile_name": "default",
        "cors": true,
        "runtime": "python3.9"
    },
    "dev": {
        "extends": "common",
        "s3_bucket": "bucket_name",
        "project_name": "test",
        
        "api_key_required": true,
        
        // Config for PRIVATE endpoint
        "endpoint_configuration": ["PRIVATE"],
        "apigateway_policy": "dev_apigateway_resource_policy.json",
        
        //Lambda configuration
        "memory_size": 512,
        "timeout_seconds": 900,
        "aws_environment_variables" : {"aws_dynamodb_table": "table_name"},
        
        "manage_roles": false,
        "role_name": "iam-role-name",
        "cloudwatch_log_level": "INFO",
        },   

}

